# find text is there inside a div with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a div like this

```
<div id="test"></div>
```

I want to find if there are any text inside the div.
how can I find it with jQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [**`:empty`**](http://api.jquery.com/empty/) selector along with [**`.is()`**](http://api.jquery.com/is/) function to achieve what you want.

Try,

```
if($('#test').is(':empty')){
  //Its empty go ahead
}
```

Or

```
if($.trim($("#test").text()) === ""){
  //Its empty go ahead
}
```

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy 
Wouldn't `$("#test").text()` suffice to check for text in an if statement?  Why did you add the `$.trim` and the `====`? Not my downvote btw.

Comment: @user3008011 $.trim( will remove the leading and the trailing spaces present in a string. and triple equal will be handy when we want to compare the value as well as its data type.